# JavaFX Canvas appendSVG Path Rendering Behavior

Tags: java, svg, javafx, rendering, vector-graphics

I am looking to draw a vector piece by piece, redrawing the vector each time a new piece is added. I have a string containing each piece of the path for the final svg that is looped through (delineated by the ";" in the string). Additionally, I added the `strokeLine` as a progress bar of sorts to track how much of the vector is drawn.

```
public void renderObject(GraphicsContext playGraphics, Canvas toUpdate)
{       
    playGraphics.beginPath();
    String toAppend = "M 215 256; L 215 256; L 215 256; L 215 256; L 225 241; L 234 231; L 246 223; L 266 214; L 284 208; L 309 204; L 340 200; L 378 199; L 416 199; L 444 199; L 473 203; L 485 206; L 496 211; L 506 218; L 510 224; L 513 233; L 515 243; L 516 257; L 512 270; L 502 285; L 493 298; L 483 308; L 476 315; L 472 318; L 469 320; L 468 320; L 468 320; L 468 320; L 468 317; L 472 309; L 480 300; L 492 293; L 510 287; L 535 283; L 557 282; L 580 283; L 593 287; L 607 295; L 623 311; L 634 333; L 640 355; L 642 396; L 639 430; L 624 467; L 602 508; L 582 536; L 557 563; L 524 585; L 490 602; L 464 611; L 432 619; L 420 621; L 404 622; L 393 622; L 383 621; L 376 620; L 372 618; L 365 610; L 360 598; L 358 578; L 357 554; L 361 514; L 371 493; L 386 463; L 412 422; L 432 395; L 456 362; L 480 329; L 506 299; L 533 271; L 560 247; L 600 213; L 620 194; L 626 189; L 629 184; L 630 182; L 632 178"; 
    for (int i=0; i < toAppend.split(";").length; i++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        playGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, toUpdate.getWidth(), toUpdate.getHeight());
        playGraphics.strokeLine(50, 50, 50+10*i, 50);

        playGraphics.appendSVGPath(toAppend.split(";")[i]);
        playGraphics.stroke();
    }
}
```

However, once implemented onto the live canvas, the vector is not drawn and only the progress bar appears visible. This is quite peculiar considering that after the rendering is complete, the vector image can be displayed in its entirety onto the canvas if the `graphicsContext` object is used again and another `playGraphics.stroke();` is invoked.

Why does `playGraphics.stroke();` fail to run but `playGraphics.strokeLine` runs fine?

[image: Progress bar indicating that rendering is occurring, but the vector is not displayed]
Progress bar indicating that rendering is occurring, but the vector is not displayed
[image]
Progress bar indicating that rendering is occurring, but the vector is not displayed
[image]
Vector finally being displayed, but only after a dot was drawn onto the canvas, reinvoking `playGraphics.stroke();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears SVG paths are somehow removed from the current path when you call `stroke()` (after which they cannot be appended to the current path).  If you were to only call `stroke()` when the loop is completed (which I realize would undermine the animation effect, and therefore is not a solution), your drawing would appear as expected.

This is complicated by the fact that your sleep calls are ignoring the threading rules of JavaFX.  Is your `renderObject` method being called in the JavaFX application thread?

- If so, the `sleep` calls are preventing the processing of events, including painting.
- If not, the GraphicsContext method calls are illegal and may fail or behave unpredictable.  From the [GraphicsContext documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html):

> … Once a `Canvas` node is attached to a scene, it must be modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.
>
> Calling any method on the `GraphicsContext` is considered modifying its corresponding `Canvas` and is subject to the same threading rules.

Once your Canvas is showing, you have to make those GraphicsContext calls in the application thread.  But, you cannot sleep in the application thread;  that causes all GUI events to hang, including all visual updates and all responses to user input.

There are a few ways to do multithreading properly.  The easiest is to create one new Thread, where `sleep` calls are permitted, while making sure your Canvas GraphicsContext calls take place in the JavaFX application thread using [Platform.runLater](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Some other notes:

- Regular expressions are expensive.  `toAppend.split(";")` is not a variable, it’s an expensive *operation.*  And you are repeating that operation *twice* in each loop iteration!  You should call `split(";")` *once*, before the loop starts, and keep the returned array in a variable.  (The JVM might be able to do this optimization at runtime, but it’s not guaranteed.)
- For that matter, you don’t need `split` at all;  you can place all of the SVG commands into an array, which has the additional benefit of being easier to read.
- Interrupts do not happen by accident.  If your thread is interrupted, it means someone is explicitly asking you to *stop what you are doing* and exit gracefully.  Ignoring an interrupt means your thread is a rogue thread that cannot be halted.  In most cases, the best thing to do is place the entire body of the method in the try/catch, so it will exit automatically if interrupted.

So, with all of the above in mind, you want something like this:

```
public void renderObject(GraphicsContext playGraphics, Canvas toUpdate)
{       
    if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread())
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Must be called in JavaFX application thread");
    }

    String[] toAppend = {
        "M 215 256", "L 215 256", "L 215 256", "L 215 256",
        "L 225 241", "L 234 231", "L 246 223", "L 266 214",
        "L 284 208", "L 309 204", "L 340 200", "L 378 199",
        "L 416 199", "L 444 199", "L 473 203", "L 485 206",
        "L 496 211", "L 506 218", "L 510 224", "L 513 233",
        "L 515 243", "L 516 257", "L 512 270", "L 502 285",
        "L 493 298", "L 483 308", "L 476 315", "L 472 318",
        "L 469 320", "L 468 320", "L 468 320", "L 468 320",
        "L 468 317", "L 472 309", "L 480 300", "L 492 293",
        "L 510 287", "L 535 283", "L 557 282", "L 580 283",
        "L 593 287", "L 607 295", "L 623 311", "L 634 333",
        "L 640 355", "L 642 396", "L 639 430", "L 624 467",
        "L 602 508", "L 582 536", "L 557 563", "L 524 585",
        "L 490 602", "L 464 611", "L 432 619", "L 420 621",
        "L 404 622", "L 393 622", "L 383 621", "L 376 620",
        "L 372 618", "L 365 610", "L 360 598", "L 358 578",
        "L 357 554", "L 361 514", "L 371 493", "L 386 463",
        "L 412 422", "L 432 395", "L 456 362", "L 480 329",
        "L 506 299", "L 533 271", "L 560 247", "L 600 213",
        "L 620 194", "L 626 189", "L 629 184", "L 630 182",
        "L 632 178"
    };

    // If the SVG string is not hard-coded, create the array here:
    // String[] toAppend = svgString.split(";");

    Runnable pathBuilder = () -> {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

            for (String segment : toAppend)
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);

                path.append(" ").append(segment);
                String pathToDraw = path.toString();

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    playGraphics.beginPath();
                    playGraphics.appendSVGPath(pathToDraw);
                    playGraphics.stroke();
                });
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // Someone wants us to exit, so fall through and return.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    Thread pathBuildingThread = new Thread(pathBuilder);
    pathBuildingThread.setDaemon(true);
    pathBuildingThread.start();
}
```

Comment: You are correct that the problem is with invoking beginStroke once instead of through each iteration. I believe this is a bug with JavaFx because it works fine if you use the formal moveTo and lineTo methods.

Comment: But the solution that I need relies on redrawing the entire object in 1 path.

Comment: I agree that it appears to be a bug.  In my opinion, `gc.appendSVGPath("M 100 100 L 200 200");` should function identically to `gc.moveTo(100, 100); gc.lineTo(200, 200);`.